# Trouble testing mongoose async hook with mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, mocha.js

I am trying to unit test a pre validate mongoose model method.

Here is the model part:

```
export const hashPassword = async function () {
  console.log('test1');
  return Promise.resolve();
};

userSchema.pre('validate', hashPassword);
```

Here is the unit test part

```
it('hash password pre save hook', async () => {
    const user = new User({
      email: 'email@email.com',
      firstName: 'firstName',
      lastName: 'lastName',
      userName: 'userName',
      password: 'password',
    });

    await user.validate();
    console.log('test2');
  });
```

And finally, the error message I have

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure
> "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

So the console.log in the method is triggered but not the second one. I reduce the code the simplest logic and I still can't make it works.

I check and I am 100% positive, it comes from the hook itself. Not from mocha, not from the hash function, it comes from the mongoose hook.

PS: Yes, I have tried to increase timeOut without success

Answer (score 0):

Since your test includes asynchronous code, you need to ensure the code completes its functionality before validation using test.

From the Mocha Documentation, to test asynchronous code:

By adding an argument (usually named done) to it() to a test callback, Mocha will know that it should wait for this function to be called to complete the test. This callback accepts both an Error instance (or subclass thereof) or a falsy value; anything else is invalid usage and throws an error (usually causing a failed test).

```
describe('User', function() {
  describe('#save()', function() {
    it('should save without error', function(done) {
      var user = new User('Luna');
      user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) done(err);
        else done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Alternatively, use the done() callback directly (which will handle an error argument, if it exists):

```
describe('User', function() {
  describe('#save()', function() {
    it('should save without error', function(done) {
      var user = new User('Luna');
      user.save(done);
    });
  });
});
```

Also, If `done()` is never called, the test will fail (with timeout error)

To know more, visit: https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Comment: Sorry but, it's not a solution. As I specified, I never exit the hash function and so, I never trigger the `done` in the `it`. And I also tried passing a `done` to the hook function without any success.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after sleeping over it, I found the cause of this issue. I had an async validator in the schema that execute a request to the database. I was not stubbing it and so, it triggered the time out.

Here is the part code that was responsible:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
      async validator(email): Promise<boolean> {
        const isNonUniqueEmail = await mongoose.model('user').exists({ email });
        return !isNonUniqueEmail;
      },
      message: 'nonUniqEmail',
    },
  },
});
```

I forgot the first stack overflow rule: sleep over your bug before asking on the Internet.